# How do I set GNOME to "focus follows mouse"?

Tags: gnome, mouse, window-manager, focus

I have two monitors that I use for development. I would like to use sloppy focus for switching between windows. sloppy focus -- whatever you mouse is hovering over is in focus.

I know it's available in ubuntu 10.04. How do you enable it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to read like a question?

Comment: I didn't know this existed, thank you very much.

Comment: @fluteflute my pleasure!

Comment: +1; I was about to ask the same question. Let me just add these words to make this more easily findable: **focus follows mouse**.

Comment: Isn't this not a duplicate, as it references gnome, while the other question deals with Unity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

System -> Preferences -> Windows

Check "Select windows when the mouse moves over them"

Comment: ubuntu 14.04,  setting not to find. any command-line help?