# 16.04 Ubuntu - cannot enable focus follows mouse

Tags: 16.04, gnome, metacity, focus

I just "updated" from 14.04 to 16.04. I like gnome metacity, but cannot get it to focus follow mouse. I've tried at least 4 methods and rebooted, without success. I've been using the net since 1991, so am an old dog who REALLY hates clicking, and esp raising current window if I'm referring to another window.

Comment: You tried this? `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode 'mouse'`

Comment: I did - no effect.

Comment: or http://askubuntu.com/questions/3037/how-do-i-set-gnome-to-focus-follows-mouse?rq=1